# Name or rename list object in R with str_c() or paste()

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to rename a list object where the object name is being put together with either str_c() or paste(), but can't seem to get it to work. I'd assume this is possible, but I can't figure out how.

```
# some data
params <- tibble(col1=c(1,2,3), col2=c("a", "b", "c"))

# create empty list
all_output <- list()

# append new df to list
all_output <- append(all_output, list("this_works_fine" = params))

# append new df to list using the concatenated string
all_output <- append(all_output, list(str_c("this_", "does_", "not_", "work") = params))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either `setNames` or

```
append(all_output, setNames(list(params), str_c("this_", "does_", "not_", "work")))
```

-output

```
$this_works_fine
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   col1 col2 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c    

$this_does_not_work
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   col1 col2 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c
```

or use `lst` from `dplyr` with `:=`

```
append(all_output, lst(!!str_c("this_", "does_", "not_", "work") := params))
```

-output

```
$this_works_fine
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   col1 col2 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c    

$this_does_not_work
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   col1 col2 
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1 a    
2     2 b    
3     3 c
```